# How to zip URLs and download

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wish to download the array of images as a zip file, and is trying with jszip. Unfortunately, the zip file that is downloaded contain 2 documents, each containing the URL string instead of the actual image. What did I do wrong?

`photos` is an array of static media URLs as below

```js
[
  "/trap-camera-auto-curation/static/media/tree.2da1e271.jpeg", 
  "/trap-camera-auto-curation/static/media/sunset.a4ff3009.jpeg"
]
```

```html
<button
  onClick={() => handleDownload(props.shortlisted)}
>
  Download
</button>
```

```js
const handleDownload = (photos) => {
  const zip = require("jszip")();
  photos.forEach((photo, index) => {
    zip.file(index, photo);
  });
  zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then((content) => {
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The url needs to be converted to binary content before adding to zip.

```
const handleDownload = (photos) => {
    const zip = require("jszip")();
    let count = 0;
    photos.forEach((photo, index) => {
      const fileName = photo
        .replace(/[\/]/gi, "")
        .replace("trap-camera-auto-curationstaticmedia", "");

      JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(photo, function (err, data) {
        zip.file(fileName, data, { binary: true });
        count++;
        if (count === photos.length) {
          zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
            saveAs(content, "auto-curation-photos.zip");
          });
        }
      });
    });
  };
```